# Add carriers in a prestashop product in php

Tags: php, prestashop

I am creating a product in php in prestashop, I have more elements to add and I arrive in the delivery part and I would like to know if we can add a carrier (see image) in php.

Thanks [image]

Comment: Why you need to add a carrier in the product creation? It is useful only if you want that product to be available only using a specific carrier, is that your case? If not you should be able to just ignore that property.

Answer (score 0):

In order to link a product with specific carriers you should use the **setCarriers()** method inside the Product.php class,
or manually insert *id_product* / *id_carrier* / *id_shop* row(s) inside the **ps_product_carrier** DB table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't get the function to work, here is what I did :
`$product->setCarriers([1 => 1]);`

Answer (score 0):

I went to my database and searched for **ps_product_carrier**

```php
Db::getInstance()->execute('INSERT INTO `ps_product_carrier` (`id_product`, `id_carrier_reference`, `id_shop`) VALUES (' . $product->id . ', ' . $xml->idCarrier . ', ' . (int)Context::getContext()->shop->id . ');');
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me
I'v created a atrigger with this insert

```
INSERT INTO pr2_product_carrier (id_product, id_carrier_reference, id_shop) 
VALUES (NEW.id_product, '10', '1');
```

My id_carrier is 10.

I could understand this solution is not acceptable for many cases that you could need. In my case it was enough so I just have one carrier and I dont need hangled with others.

Best regards.